# Problems with javascript print function

Tags: javascript, php, printing

I have this javascript code to print html table from a PHP document.

```
function printReport()
{
    var data = '<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">';           
    data += '<input type="button" value="Close this page" onClick="window.close()">';
    data += '<table border="0"';
    data += $('#reportTable').html();
    data += '</table>';

    myWindow=window.open('','','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=500,height=400');
    myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
    myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
    myWindow.screenX = 0;
    myWindow.screenY = 0;
    myWindow.document.write(data);
    myWindow.focus();
};
```

It opens the new windows, displays the content right, the close button works fine, however the print button doesnt work.

My printer is working properly, I printed from word or any other app and works fine.

My problem is: the print function `window.print()` is NOT working.

If anyone could give me a hand, would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Where are you using `window.print()`?

Comment: @Joren its in the print this page data section. 

which browser is this on? Maybe the web inspector (in chrome), or firebug (in firefox) may shed some light on the issue....

Comment: @KleberBH - See my answer below. It's not that your button was not working, it was simply the case that your page didn't have any valid HTML content since the `<table>` tag was not closed.

Comment: I tried on IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
data += '<table border="0"';
```

to

```
data += '<table border="0">';
```

and tell us the net result. Tested with simple HTML content within the table. Assuming your `.html()` call returns valid table data, the window should be printable now.

**Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/aV85r/**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed and tested again and still not working. I tested on IE and Chrome, both not working. I believe my data is returning fine, because it is displaying right.

Comment: Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aV85r/. You'll have to allow pop-ups for jsfiddle.net in Chrome. Clicking on the Print button opens the print dialog for me. The only difference between my code and yours is the data that is being inserted in the table and the table tag is closed properly.

Comment: OK, I tried on Chrome again with the changes and works fine, IE still not working, only the Chrome is not keeping the table formatting like the IE.

Comment: At this point, I can only blame `$('#reportTable').html()` assuming that you have already corrected the table tag. Did you try the fiddle in IE?

Comment: Yes, I tried the fiddle on IE and doesn't work. It is working fine on Chrome. Guessing could be some setting on IE.

Comment: If instead click button I press ctrl p, it print normal from any browser. just my button is not working on IE for some reason.

Comment: I printed by clicking on your button. BTW, did you disable the popup on IE?

Comment: Ok, I am displaying the tollbar on the popup and can print from there or from pressing ctrl P, it works on any browser and do the job. Thanks a lot or the help.